# Unexpected Token field @ error

Tags: groovy

I am getting unexpected token error on line 8 and 10 . Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
if (! underlyingIssue) {
    // we must be on create screen and there is no reported set on the issue yet
    return
}

def fieldExemption = getFieldById(getFieldChanged())

def fieldException expiration (must be <= 364 days) = getFieldByName("Exception expiration (must be <= 364 days)")

if (fieldExemption.getValue() && underlyingIssue.reporter.name == "reporter") {
    fieldException expiration (must be <= 364 days).setRequired(false)
} else {
    fieldAException expiration (must be <= 364 days).setRequired(true)
}
```

Comment: What's `def fieldException expiration (must be <= 364 days) = getFieldByName("Exception expiration (must be <= 364 days)")
` supposed to mean?  You can't just stick `(must be <= 364 days)` in a variable definition

Comment: I am trying to make a field mandatory depending on other data entered on the issue screen during an issue creation. 

Here is the situation: 
Field " Exception expiration (must be <= 364 days)" needs to be required if Field " Exemption " checked as " No" .

Field " Exception expiration (must be <= 364 days)" needs to be deactivated if " Field " Exemption " checked as " Yes " .

I am not familiar with script writing. Any help will be appricaited.

Thank you.